# Efficient calculations of paths with shared subpaths in directed graph

Tags: data-structures, graph, path, tree

I need a recommendation for an efficient datastructure that suits my problem of calculating the path costs inside a directed graph under the contraint, that many paths sometimes share a same subpath for which I do not want to make the calculations twice.

Each number in these lists are refering to a node inside a directed graph. Each line describes one path:

```
[121, 85, 135, 99, 141, 134, 4, 33, 65, 131, 18, 127],
[121, 85, 135, 99, 141, 134, 65, 33, 4, 127],
[121, 85, 135, 99, 141, 134, 65, 33, 4, 131, 18, 127],
[121, 85, 135, 99, 141, 134, 65, 33, 4, 107, 127],
[121, 85, 135, 99, 141, 134, 65, 23, 18, 127],
[121, 85, 135, 99, 141, 134, 65, 23, 18, 131, 4, 127],
[121, 85, 135, 99, 141, 134, 65, 23, 18, 131, 4, 107, 127],
[121, 85, 135, 99, 141, 134, 65, 107, 4, 127],
[121, 85, 135, 99, 141, 134, 65, 107, 4, 131, 18, 127],
[121, 85, 135, 99, 141, 134, 65, 107, 127],
[121, 85, 135, 99, 141, 134, 65, 131, 18, 127],
[121, 85, 135, 99, 141, 134, 65, 131, 4, 127],
[121, 85, 135, 99, 141, 134, 65, 131, 4, 107, 127],
[121, 85, 135, 99, 141, 4, 127],
...
```

As one can see in this example many paths share the same subset of nodes along the way. (And many other paths [not shown here] do not share a subpath.)

I want to compute the 'optimality' of each path, i.e. the sum OR products of the weights along the way. These weights can be seen as constant for my graph while traversing each path.

To be clear: I want to avoid calculating the weight of the path from node 121 to node 141 for all shown paths in this example, as these multiplications / additions of the weights between two nodes is the same (up to node 141) in each of the shown paths...

I am satisfied with a datastructure recommendation and explanation why the mentioned datastructure is best suited for my needs.
If you also have a library recommendation I would prefer one in C/C++ or Python.

Comment: What have you tried so far? please include your python/c code

Comment: @JonasPraem: Naive and repetitive calculations of the 'path length' by multiplying my weights between nodes along the way over millions and millions of different paths, before realising that this scheme is much to inefficient and thus coming here to ask this very question as my background is electrical engineering not computer science or advanced mathematics, which is why I lack datastructure knowledge.

Comment: `functools.lru_cache` decorator in Python to speed up calculations?

Comment: How are the paths given? If you need to perform `O(k)` operations to read a path of length `k`, then you might as well sum or multiply up the weights at no additional cost.

Comment: Something general: Currently I am using the Boost Graph Library (C++) and do my prototyping in Python. Although the Lemon Graph Lib looks nice. But to be honest I do not care how I am doing the calculations and if I have to write something on my own or use a lib. MykolaZotko: Thanks for your note. @CătălinFrâncu: My question is about the best suited datastructure / algorithm. I _dont_ want to read each path while summing. This would lead to the same computations over and over. This is why I am searching for a different solution. I thought about some tree structure (root eq. start node)...

Comment: Gotcha. Another thought: do your paths come in sorted order? If so, you can precompute the data and store each path as <length of the common prefix with the previous path> + <new path>. The second path would be <6>, <65, 33, 4, 127>. Additionaly, you'd store a partial sum array which would give you O(1) lookups of partial sums. It is unclear how much time this approach saves. Again, it depends on how you receive the path list.

Comment: Yes I thought about storing partial sums, but I do not know how / where to store. What data structure should I use?